# Smoothing out mesh with holes

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

I am making holes in my mesh to put tubes inside. The problem is that it doesnt work well with subsurf. I know one way to fix it but it changes the shape too much. I have made a video to show what i am doing. Hopefully some can provide diferent ways to do it. I have tried boolean mod but it turns out the same way.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=28U5_XMF5dE

Comment: Check here: http://topologyguides.com/image/124120926080 and here: http://topologyguides.com/post/152907366360/cutting-circular-holes-in-curved-surfaces also check the main site for sub-d modeling tips.

Comment: That's what happens when using Ngons with Subsurf (tris will also cause that if they are located near the mesh corners)

Comment: It happends when not using ngons as well.....

Comment: Generally it doesn't. Using tips from topology-guides is the easiest way to get that

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things you could do differently that will help...

1. Apply Rotation & Scale before going into Edit Mode. That will keep your use of the Looptools > Circle from creating ovals.
2. Add an extra vertical edge loop in the middle of each section where you plan to put the holes.
3. Add an extra horizontal edge loop that cuts across all three hole areas.
4. THEN start doing the extrude/scale operation(s), followed by use of Looptools > Circle to create the holes.

Doing it this way will give you eight-sided holes which work out better in the long run.

Comment: How about subdividing instead if placing edgeloops vertically and horisontally?

Comment: The way I wrote it out is the way I learned it. Subdividing may be a bit faster, but I've never done it that way, so to me, it sounds like a recipe for trouble. :)